# Symfony, Doctrine - Map result of query to custom class and not entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Lets say I have an entity called `User` which holds `roles`,`username`, `salt`, `password`, `fullName` and `firstName`.

I am using Symfony with Doctrine so when I create an `User` entity I have `UserRepository` which extends `EntityRepository`

In this `UserRepository` I can make a function `getOneUser` (It has by default one but bear with me) and inside I will have

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('user')->
where('user.username = :username')->
setParameter('username', $username)->
getQuery->
getResult()
```

This will return an object from `User` entity.

What I want is to have a model called `ProfileViewModel` which represends an `User` but only the information needed to the view.  It won't have properies like `salt` or `password` or any information not needed for the rendering of the `profileView`

Is there a way to the function `getOneUser` to map its result to `ProfileViewModel` and not `User` entity?

Comment: You can do this with [Result Set Mappings](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) Might also take a look at partials.  But quite frankly, Doctrine ORM really wants one entity per table and does not lend itself to this sort of thing.  Easier, in my opinion, to just use the DBAL layer and create your own custom objects from sql results.

Comment: Doctrine Named Native Queries http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#named-native-query

Comment: Doctrine Custom hydrator http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html#writing-hydration-method

Comment: What is the problem to use a User entity? you could even set some fields to empty after loading.

Comment: @FrankB what I want is for my views to only have access to what they use. I don't want my view to have access to the `salt` or `password` or any other field it doesnt need.  Each view should have its own Model and it should use only the model to represent data. The thing is...I don't want to make `User` entity and then from it make `ProfileViewModel` because then there is an extra layer of actions. I want to remove one layer of actions so that the result is mapped directly to whatever it needs.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax